# Вывести значение из массива php

Tags: php, массивы

сильно не пинайте, знания PHP стартовые:) 
Не получается вывести значение из массива (необходимо вывести дату [formatted] и время [time] и [timeto].

```
print_r( $jckwds->get_reserved_slot() );
```

выводит следующее:

```
Array ( [id] => 20170624_0 [date] => Array ( [formatted] => 24/06/2017 [id] => 20170624 ) [time] => Array ( [timefrom] => Array ( [time] => 02:30 [stripped] => 0230 ) [timeto] => Array ( [time] => 10:45 [stripped] => 1045 ) [cutoff] => [lockout] => 4 [shipping_methods] => Array ( [0] => any ) [fee] => Array ( [value] => [formatted] => €0,00 ) [days] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1 [2] => 6 ) [id] => 0 [time_id] => 02301045 [formatted] => 02:30 AM - 10:45 AM     [formatted_with_fee] => 02:30 AM - 10:45 AM [value] => 0|0.00 ) )
```

Код, которым пытаюсь вывести хотя бы дату:

```
global $jckwds;
$jckw =  $jckwds->get_reserved_slot();

foreach($jckw as $key) {
    echo $key('date');
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/book.array.php

Answer (score 2):

Для того чтобы легко понять структуру многомерного массива, в первую очередь посмотрите на строение.

```
Array ( [id] => 20170624_0
        [date] => Array ( [formatted] => 24/06/2017 [id] => 20170624 ) 
        [time] => Array ( [timefrom] => Array ( [time] => 02:30 [stripped] => 0230 ) 
        [timeto] => Array ( [time] => 10:45 [stripped] => 1045 )
        [cutoff] => [lockout] => 4 
        [shipping_methods] => Array ( [0] => any ) 
        [fee] => Array ( [value] => [formatted] => €0,00 ) 
        [days] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1 [2] => 6 ) 
        [id] => 0
        [time_id] => 02301045
        [formatted] => 02:30 AM - 10:45 AM
        [formatted_with_fee] => 02:30 AM - 10:45 AM
        [value] => 0|0.00 ) )
```

Дальше через `foreach` можете получить пару ключ=>значение

```
foreach($jckw as $key=>$val) {
  echo $val;
  /* или */
  echo $jckw[$key];
   }
```

В переменной `$val` уже находятся значения, их можно получать и без ключа, если вам нужно получить одно значение по ключу, например

`echo $jckw['date']['formatted'];` или  `echo $jckw['time']['timefrom']['time'];`

Answer (score 0):

К элементу массива обращаются через квадратные скобки. Круглые — это вызов функции.

К тому же `date` — это массив и `echo` в данном случае выведет `Array` вместо даты.